# Replace bad character from a string Matlab

Tags: matlab, replace, character

I try to create a function that take a char in paramater :

```
function replaceBadCharacters(name)

    BadChar = '<>:"/\|?*';
    bad = ismember(BadChar, name);
    if contains(name, ' ') || any(BadChar)
        name = strrep(name, ' ', '_'); 
        name = strrep(name, BadChar(bad), '_'); 
    end
end
```

and i would like to replace `space` and `BadChar` from the char and replace it by a `_`. But my function isn't working.

For example i have a char `Manager principal` or `Manager/principal` and i would like to change it to `Manager_principal`

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function works correctly but hasn't any defined return parameters. Replace the first line by

```
function name_corrected = replaceBadCharacters(name)
```

and it'll work. Compare the [documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) or type `doc function` in the MATLAB command line to study the full syntactic possibilities.

Comment: The function does not work correctly, `if contains(name, ' ') || any(BadChar)` does not what OP think it does.

Comment: Thanks @gehbiszumeis ! But when i call the function in my main file like this : 

    replaceBadCharacters(component_NameValue);

(component_NameValue is a char value which contains "Manager principal") it never enter in the function i don't know why.

Comment: @gehbiszumeis when i try my function in a simple .m file it's working but when i put under my main function the function replaceBadCharacters() it isn't working

Comment: Originally, MATLAB wants you to put every function in a separate `*.m`, add its path to the workspace and call it in your script equally to any other (builtin) MATLAB function. As of MATLAB2016b you can also add local functions to your script (which I understand is what you want to do) by  include the function AT THE END of a script file

Comment: BTW: @rinkert gave a nice hint about, what in your function is incorrect, while it still does what you want. Another hint on that: Is there a situation, where the statement `any(BadChar)` is not `true`?

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: As stated in [gehbiszumeis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55591773/11089932), the actual problem is the missing return value. I'm sorry for not pointing that out in the first place.

---

Your function can be simplified to this:

```matlab
function name = replaceBadCharacters(name)

  BadChar = '<>:"/\|?* ';
  bad = ismember(name, BadChar);
  name(bad) = '_';

end
```

You can simply add the "space" to your `BadChar` char array. Also, please have a look at [Indexing with Logical Values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-3).

Some tests:

```matlab
>> replaceBadCharacters('Manager principal')
ans = Manager_principal

>> replaceBadCharacters('Manager/principal')
ans = Manager_principal

>> replaceBadCharacters('Manager?principal')
ans = Manager_principal
```

Comment: Thanks @HansHirse ! I will probably use your function as it is shortest and clearest than mine

Answer (score 1):

I think using replace is the best option and if you can use string you get a performance boost too. Here is a comparison:

```
>> replaceBadCharacters_ismember("Manager principal");
Elapsed time is 9.271434 seconds.

>> replaceBadCharacters_replace_char("Manager principal");
Elapsed time is 2.021813 seconds.

>> replaceBadCharacters_replace_string("Manager principal");
Elapsed time is 0.856642 seconds.

function result = replaceBadCharacters_ismember(name)

    BadChar = '<>:"/\|?* ';

    tic
    for i = 1:1e6
        result = name;
        bad = ismember(result, BadChar);
        result(bad) = '_';
    end
    toc
end

function result = replaceBadCharacters_replace_char(name)

    name = char(name);
    BadChar = ["<" ">" """" "\" "/" "|" "?" "*" " "];

    tic
    for i = 1:1e6
        result = replace(name, BadChar, '_');
    end
    toc
end

function result = replaceBadCharacters_replace_string(name)

    name = string(name);
    BadChar = ["<" ">" """" "\" "/" "|" "?" "*" " "];

    tic
    for i = 1:1e6
        result = replace(name, BadChar, '_');
    end
    toc
end
```

Comment: Nice answer! Instead of `tic`/`toc`, do `timeit(@()replaceBadCharacters_ismember("Manager principal"))`. In this case, you can remove the loop from each of the functions you want to time. `timeit` takes care of running your function as often as necessary to obtain an accurate estimate of time taken. If the time is too short, use a longer string as input.